# Convert from oga to mp3 using pydub: ffmpeg returned error code: 1

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, chocolatey, pydub

I want to take an OGA file within a binary stream and convert it into mp3 using also another stream. I'm getting a permissions error even with running VSCode as administrator. This is my code:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
AudioSegment.converter = "C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\ffmpeg\\tools\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe"

input_stream = io.BytesIO()
input_stream.seek(0) 
await new_file.download_to_memory(input_stream)
 
# Create an audio segment from the binary stream
audio = AudioSegment.from_file(input_stream, format='ogg')

# Create an output stream for the MP3 data
output_stream = io.BytesIO()

# Export the audio to MP3 using ffmpeg and write the output to the stream
audio.export(output_stream, format='mp3', codec='libmp3lame')

# Get the MP3 data from the output stream
mp3_data = output_stream.getvalue()
```

Error message:

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\_application.py", line 1124, in process_update
    await coroutine
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\_handler.py", line 141, in handle_update
    return await self.callback(update, context)
  File "c:\Users\jdbol\OneDrive\Desktop\testbots\echobot.py", line 80, in voice_to_text
    audio = AudioSegment.from_file(input_stream, format='ogg')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 773, in from_file     
    raise CouldntDecodeError(
pydub.exceptions.CouldntDecodeError: Decoding failed. ffmpeg returned error code: 1

Output from ffmpeg/avlib:

ffmpeg version 6.0-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
  libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
  libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
  libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
fd:: End of file
```

I ran the command in a terminal and the file converted without an issue:

```
ffmpeg -i .\file_12.oga output.mp3
```

1. I'm not sure if the .exe file must be included into the path. When I don't do it, What I get is a permissions error.
2. What other codecs can be used here?
3. Is it possible to use oga files? I tried to declare this but I got an 'Unknown input format: 'oga' message `(audio = AudioSegment.from_file(input_stream, format='oga')`)

Thanks!

UPDATE: I created a more simple version that is not using a binary stream and worked like a charm, so we know for sure that something is happening with the BytesIO object

```
async def voice_to_text(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    # Get the absolute path of the script
    filename = 'file_9.oga'
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    # Construct the file paths for input and output files
    input_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, filename)
    output_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + ".mp3")

    # Load the OGA audio file
    audio = AudioSegment.from_file(input_file_path, format='ogg')

    # Export the audio to MP3 format
    audio.export(output_file_path, format='mp3')

    print("Conversion complete. MP3 file saved as:", output_file_path)
```

UPDATE 2: It seems like `await new_file.download_to_memory(input_stream)` is the problematic line. I tried to save the file and its corrupt. Not sure how to use this method then.

https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.file.html#telegram.File.download_to_memory